# Jquery .remove() doesn't change .length

Tags: jquery

I have an icon that when clicked uses .remove() to remove the paragraph it is in from the DOM.  The paragraphs all have the class .cart-item.

Immediately after the paragraph is removed, I create an object containing all the paragraphs with the .cart-item class, then check the object's .length to see if it is zero.

It seems that the .length property is not updated when a paragraph is removed.  For example, if there are 2 qualifying paragraphs and I remove one of them, the check on the length returns 2, not 1.

Here is my code.

```
$("#cart").on("click", ".cart-delete-item", function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    var items = $(".cart-item");
    if ($(items).length === 0) {
        $("#checkout-btn").addClass("disabled");
        $("#checkout-btn").prop("disabled", true);
    }
})
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<p class="cart-item">
    <small><i class="fa fa-trash text-danger mr-2 cart-delete-item"></i>1 T-shirt @ $20</small>
</p> –
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `cart-item` is a child of the direct `parent` of the `cart-delete-item` clicked?  Can you share an example of the markup?

Comment: I am somewhat sure you are not removing the ".cart-item" class itself, can you post your html?

Comment: To make sure you remove the right thing, do `$(this).closest(".cart-item").remove();`

Comment: The cart-item paragraph is definitely being removed, I see it disappear on the screen.  Each cart-item paragraph is inserted by another jquery function in my ode and the html looks like this: <p class="cart-item"><small><i class="fa fa-trash text-danger mr-2 cart-delete-item"></i>1 T-shirt @ $20</small></p>

Comment: Please add the HTML to the question so you can format it readably.

Comment: `$(this).parent()` is the `<small>` element, not `<p class="cart-item">`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I missed the implication of having <small> in the html, it's all working now.

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).parent()` is the `<small>` element, not the `<p class="cart-item">`, so you're not removing the item from the cart, you're just removing the name and delete button from the item.

Use `$(this).closest(".cart-item").remove()`. Then you won't be dependent on the specific nesting level.